# Async REST API Request IONIC

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to save data into an `IonicStorageModule`  from a request to my REST API, the data is user info like; Name, Phone, Address, etc.

Right now I  have this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ServicioApiProvider {
  results:Object[];
  loading:boolean;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.results = [];
    this.loading = false;

  }

  buscar(ruta) {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(ruta)
        .toPromise()
        .then(
            res => { // Success
            this.results = res.json();
            console.log(res.json());
            resolve();
            },
            msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
            }
          );
      });

      console.log("Last line"); 
      return promise;
   }
}
```

But always the line: `"console.log("Last line");"` executes before the promise.

Any Ideas to save the response from the REST API to an IonicStorageModule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `http.get` method is async, if you want that line to be executed when the data is ready, place it inside of the `then`. You can also simplify your `buscar(...)` method like this:

```
buscar(ruta): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(ruta)
        .map(res => res.json())     // Get the body of the response
        .toPromise()                // Convert the observable into a promise
        .then(
            response => {           // Success callback

                this.results = response;
                console.log(response);

                // Since the http get is async, you need to place the logic
                // to save the data in the storage here!
                // ...
                // this.storage.set('data', JSON.stringify(response));
                // ...

                console.log("Last line"); 
            },
            error => {              // Error callback

                // TODO: Handle error
                // ...

                console.log(error);
                return error;
            });
}
```

**EDIT**

> I'm calling this method from one
>   page:this.servicioApi.buscar(this.path); After that I want to access
>   to the data that I saved in storage, but it returns null (And the get
>   to access to the storage variable executes before the call to the
>   method "buscar"), and if I access to the data from another page it
>   returns the JSON

Let me modify again the method, in order to return the response:

```
buscar(ruta): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(ruta)
        .map(res => res.json())     // Get the body of the response
        .toPromise()                // Convert the observable into a promise
        .then(
            response => {           // Success callback

                this.results = response;
                console.log(response);

                // Since the http get is async, you need to place the logic
                // to save the data in the storage here!
                // ...
                // this.storage.set('data', JSON.stringify(response));
                // ...

                console.log("Last line");

                // UPDATE: return the response
                return response;


            },
            error => {              // Error callback

                // TODO: Handle error
                // ...

                console.log(error);

                // UPDATE: return null if there was an error
                return null;
            });
}
```

So now we're returning the response (or `null` if there was an error). That gives us two ways of getting that data when calling that method:

1) Getting the response from the callback

```
this.servicioApi.buscar(this.path).then(res => {
    if(res) {
      // Here you can use the response
      // ...
    } else {
      // Here you can do something if there was an error
      // ...
    }
});
```

2) Getting the response from the storage

```
this.servicioApi.buscar(this.path).then(() => {
    this.storage.get('data').then(responseJson => {
      if(responseJson) {

        // Parse the response since it is a JSON
        let response = JSON.parse(responseJson);

        // Here you can use the response
        // ...
      }
    });
});
```

**EDIT II**

Just like @Sampath mentioned, you could just use `observables` (which is Angular recommended way), like this:

```
buscar(ruta): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(ruta)
        .map(res => res.json())     // Get the body of the response
        .map(response => {

                this.results = response;
                console.log(response);

                // Since the http get is async, you need to place the logic
                // to save the data in the storage here!
                // ...
                // this.storage.set('data', JSON.stringify(response));
                // ...

                return response;
            });
}
```

And then just subscribe to that method:

```
this.servicioApi.buscar(this.path)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
          // Here you can use the response
          // ...
        },
        error => {

            // TODO: Handle error
            // ...

            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Just one question, I'm calling this method from one page:this.servicioApi.buscar(this.path); After that I want to access to the data that I saved in storage, but it returns null (And the get to access to the storage variable executes before the call to the method "buscar"), and if I access to the data from another page it returns the JSON

Comment: Oh yeah!, Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: Nice. One question. Why can't we do this with default `observable` here?

Comment: @Sampath It can be done with just `observable`  (in fact, I usually use observables instead of promises) but since the user was wrapping the method inside of a promise, I thought he wanted to use promises instead of observables.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe he doesn't know about the power of `observables`. Anyway,  we would like to have more options for a single problem :)

Comment: @Sampath thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the answer to include that information as well :)

Comment: Excellent. But unfortunately, I don't have any `upvotes` for this post :D